# IPython : groupby column to find processing time

Tags: pandas, ipython

I have a dataframe which produces output as

```
COL1     COL 2         COL3
abc      143613948     143614469
abc      143613945     143614466
xyz      164859569     164901557
xyz      164859531     164900406
```

How can  COL1 be grouped to derive a new column which is max(COL3) - min (COL2)?

Desired output will look like dataframe:

```
COL1      COL4
abc       524
xyz       42026
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `agg`

```
agg = df.groupby('COL1').agg(dict(COL2='min', COL3='max'))
(agg.COL3 - agg.COL2).reset_index(name='COL4')

  COL1   COL4
0  abc    524
1  xyz  42026
```

using `apply`

```
df.groupby('COL1').apply(
    lambda d: d.COL3.max() - d.COL2.min()).reset_index(name='COL4')

  COL1   COL4
0  abc    524
1  xyz  42026
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, while using "agg" I am getting following error in iPython notebook :   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I am able to resolved above issue, it works like charm !!

Comment: Assume I have another column in original column say ID.                              `COL1     COL 2         COL3               ID
abc      143613948     143614469      100
abc      143613945     143614466      100
xyz      164859569     164901557       500
xyz      164859531     164900406       500`                                                      How can I get output by adding ID column as well on groupby result                                                                                                          `COL1   COL4    ID
0  abc    524        100
1  xyz  42026      500`